# Dart: 2 lists, show elements of list a that aren't in list b

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to compare 2 lists. (Dart (flutter))

```
List a = [1,2,3,4]
List b = [2,3]
```

I want to find the elements of List a that aren't in List b.
Outcome:

```
List c = [1,4]
```

Which method should I use? From math at school, I know you can use intersection to find the communal elements, but don't know the name for this 'method'.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is much easier if you use sets instead of lists: the [Set.difference](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.0/dart-core/Set/difference.html) method does exactly this.

Alternatively, if you want the output to be a list (to maintain the ordering from list `a`), the most efficient way is still to store the elements from list `b` in a set, then use a loop over list `a` to build the list `c` out of the elements which aren't in set `b`, using the [Set.contains](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.0/dart-core/Set/contains.html) method.

Comment: Thank you for your help and answer! I 'converted' the lists to set , used the difference method and 'converted' it back to list. It works!